# Launch Screen File resizes my previous xib layouts

Tags: ios, xcode, screen, xib, launch

I have an app with multiple xib files, some of them complex to build and has been working faultlessly until this new obligation from apple to create a storyboard launch screen. If build and run (XCode 11.4) without storyboard app runs without problems but if I add the launch screen the main.xib interface is messed up.

Is there any way I can force to work "as before adding the storyboard"? Do I have to rebuild all the xib interface to storyboard (big job)?

Thanks!

Josep

Comment: Seems odd that using a launch screen would change your xib layouts... Can you provide a simple example? You may just need to make a minor change to the way you are loading your xibs.

Comment: What is really happening is that when I add the storyboard it no longer autoresizes the view in different devices as before... I suppose I will need to add constrains or...